# Kayleigh alternative for Linux

Tags: printing

I wanted to ask if anyone know is there any Linux alternative for Kayleigh that I could use for our Sharp printers (MX-2651)? I need print server that would be compatible with SHARP OSA and allow me to make user accounts that users could log in with on printers.

I know it's kinda long shot but since it looks like Sharp OSA can use custom software so maybe someone managed to make some alternative like CUPS work?